# Laravel StoreAs Returns FALSE and does not upload the image

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10, laravel-filesystem

I'm working with Laravel v10, and I wanted to upload a picture into the directory `public/frontend/images/home`, so at the Controller, I tried this:

```
public function submitHomeBoxes(Request $request)
{
    try {
        $pageImage = Page::where('pag_type', 'home');
        if ($request->hasFile('box_image_1')) {
            $boxImage = $request->file('box_image_1');
            $imageName = $boxImage->getClientOriginalName();
            $imagePath = $boxImage->storeAs('public/frontend/images/home');
            $pageImage->where('pag_name', 'box_image_1')->update(['pag_value' => $imageName]);
            dd($imagePath); // returns false
        }

        return redirect()->back()->withSuccess('Image Uploaded');
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        dd($e);
    }
}
```

But it does not upload the picture somehow, and `dd($imagePath)` returns `false`!

So what's going wrong here? How can I solve this issue?

---

### **UPDATE**:

I made some changes on the method to get the error, but still do not know what the error is:

```
try{
            $pageImage = Page::where('pag_type', 'home');
            if ($request->hasFile('box_image_1')) {
                $boxImage = $request->file('box_image_1');
                $imageName = $boxImage->getClientOriginalName();
                $imagePath = $boxImage->storeAs('public/frontend/images/home');
                if ($imagePath === false) {
                    $error = $boxImage->getError();
                    dd($error); //returns 0
        
                }
                $pageImage->where('pag_name', 'box_image_1')->update(['pag_value' => $imageName]);
                // dd($imagePath); return false
            }

        }catch (Exception $e) {
            dd($boxImage->getErrorMessage());
        }
```

Comment: storeAs() eturns false if the file fails to be stored. Find the error if its failing: dd($boxImage->getErrorMessage());

Comment: What @KarlHill wrote: Do the appropriate error handling.

Comment: @KarlHill Would you check my updated code plz

Comment: What's the error? Does it actually throw an exception?

Comment: Also, add some debugging code to check the size of the uploaded file before attempting to store it. $fileSize = $boxImage->getSize();
dd($fileSize);

Comment: Update this line to: $imagePath = $boxImage->storeAs('public/frontend/images/home', $imageName);

Answer (score 0):

The [storeAs()](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/filesystem#specifying-a-file-name) method requires two parameters. The directory where the file should be stored and the desired file name.

```
$imagePath = $boxImage->storeAs('public/frontend/images/home', $imageName);
```

---

```
public function submitHomeBoxes(Request $request)
{
    try {
        $pageImage = Page::where('pag_type', 'home');
        if ($request->hasFile('box_image_1')) {
            $boxImage = $request->file('box_image_1');
            $imageName = $boxImage->getClientOriginalName();
            $imagePath = $boxImage->storeAs('public/frontend/images/home', $imageName);
            if ($boxImage->getError() !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
                dd($boxImage->getErrorMessage());
            }
            $pageImage->where('pag_name', 'box_image_1')->update(['pag_value' => $imageName]);
        }

        return redirect()->back()->withSuccess('Image Uploaded');
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        dd($e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, now dd($imagePath) correctly returns the path but still the image is not find there and not uploaded yet :(

Comment: Is it possible that the file is being stored in a different location than you think?